# Sharepoint online powershell script to get all field properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

Is there a way in SharePoint Online to get Field Properties? For example, I have a lookup column and for this I want its Field Type, Required, Get information from:
Allow Multiple Values: Checked or not, Description. I know we can get it like this:

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$context.Credentials = $creds
$web = $context.Web
$list=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName);
$fieldColl=$list.Fields;
$context.Load($fieldColl);
$context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach($field in $fieldColl)
{
    Write-Host $field.Title    
    Write-Host $field.Description
}
```

But I want the other properties as well.

Comment: This one is an excellent primer if you are about to create site columns and content types : https://olafd.wordpress.com/2017/05/09/create-fields-from-xml-for-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get field properties like this:

```
$columns = Get-PnPField -List "PnPList"  
foreach($column in $columns){  
    Write-Host "Column Title  :" $column.Title  
    Write-Host "Description   :" $column.Description  
    Write-Host "Group Name    :" $column.Group  
    Write-Host "Internal Name :" $column.InternalName  
    Write-Host "Static Name   :" $column.StaticName  
    Write-Host "Scope         :" $column.Scope  
    Write-Host "Type          :" $column.TypeDisplayName  
    Write-Host "Schema XML    :" $column.SchemaXml  
    Write-Host "Is Required?  :" $column.Required  
    Write-Host "Is read only? :" $column.ReadOnlyField  
    Write-Host "Unique?       :" $column.EnforceUniqueValues  
    Write-Host "-------------------------------------------"  
}
```

And for detailed definition, you could check the SchemaXml, it will have all property definition.

**EDIT** : [Script source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-list-columns-on-sharepoint-using-pnp-powershell)

Comment: When you take answer from the internet, **please credit them**. Plagiarism is not a joke. Source for this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-list-columns-on-sharepoint-using-pnp-powershell/

Comment: Is there any way to get the ID for each listed property in the schema within the choice tags? Surely there is a consistent ID associated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with PnP PowerShell using the [Get-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps) commandlet:

So something like this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite
Get-PnPField -List "Your List Name"
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

You can also get this information via REST by visiting:

```
https://yoursite.sharepiont.com/sites/yoursites/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Your List Name')/fields
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I ended up using site provisioning to transfer over my columns and content types over to the Content Type Hub.

Login through PnP PowerShell

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -out “youroutputfile.xml” –Handlers “Fields,ContentTypes”
```

Find the file ouput.  Defauld be 
`C:\Windows\System32`

Connect to the Hub
    Connect-PnPOnline https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub

Apply the provisioned file
   `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate C:\Temp\youroutputfile.xml`

That's it!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.stackexchange.com. Thanks for contributing! I'm not sure how what you wrote about the content type hub directly answers the question about field properties. Did you mean to answer a different question?